# jQuery slider animation (slide to right)

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-animate

I am trying to make an infinity slider in jQuery. My slider is in two rows but every row is for itself. Images should move from left to right. I managed to do that but I would like to add animation so that images slide slowly. Can anyone give me an idea how to do that? Right now the images just jump from one to another.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
let item_widthFirstRow = $('.content__slider-firstRow .slide').outerWidth();
let left_valueFirstRow = item_widthFirstRow * (-1);

let item_widthSecondRow = $('.content__slider-secondRow .slide').outerWidth();
let left_valueSecondRow = item_widthSecondRow * (-1);

$('.content__slider-firstRow .slide').before($('.content__slider-firstRow .slide:last'));
$('.content__slider-secondRow .slide').before($('.content__slider-secondRow .slide:last'));

$('.content__slider-firstRow').css({ 'left': left_valueFirstRow });
$('.content__slider-secondRow').css({ 'left': left_valueSecondRow });

$('#next').click(function () {

    let left_indentFirstRow = parseInt($('.content__slider-firstRow').css('left')) + item_widthFirstRow;
    let left_indentSecondRow = parseInt($('.content__slider-secondRow').css('left')) + item_widthSecondRow;

    $('.content__slider-firstRow').animate({ 'left': left_indentFirstRow }, 'slow', function () {
        $('.content__slider-firstRow .slide:first').before($('.content__slider-firstRow .slide:last'));
        $('.content__slider-firstRow').css({ 'left': left_valueFirstRow });
    });

    $('.content__slider-secondRow').animate({ 'left': left_indentSecondRow }, "slow", function () {
        $('.content__slider-secondRow .slide:first').before($('.content__slider-secondRow .slide:last'));
        $('.content__slider-secondRow').css({ 'left': left_valueSecondRow });
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pong93/39wcktrb/33/

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then provide your HTML in a working snippet using the editor.

Comment: Not what I suggested. The editor provides the means to create a demo right in your question. Also, all information should be up there, not down here in a comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.